# How can I select :last-child in d3.js?

Tags: select, d3.js

I need to manipulate the `text` elements of the first and last tick of an axis to bring them more towards the center.

I am trying to select them, one at the time, with something like `svg.select('.tick:last-child text')` but it doesn't work. I'd then apply `.transform('translate(4,0)')`...

Am I doing something wrong? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it doesn't work and maybe give an example please? It should work in principle.

Comment: Using `.tick:first-child` should work, but `.tick:last-child` will not. The first- and last-child selectors select elements *if they are the first or last child of their parent* not just the first or last of their particular type. A tick is never the last child of its parent element on a d3 axis, because the parent `g` element contains the path for the axis itself as well as the ticks, and that path comes after the ticks, making it the last child. You can easily find the first and last element of a `.selectAll` however. See my answer below.

Comment: @jshanley You can use `:last-of-type` instead of `:last-child`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One thing you could do is to create custom sub-selections by adding methods to `d3.selection.prototype`. You could create a `selection.first()` method that selects the first item in a selection, and a `selection.last()` method that selects the last item. For instance:

```
d3.selection.prototype.first = function() {
  return d3.select(this[0][0]);
};
d3.selection.prototype.last = function() {
  var last = this.size() - 1;
  return d3.select(this[0][last]);
};
```

This would let you do the following:

```
var tickLabels = svg.selectAll('.tick text');

tickLabels.first()
  .attr('transform','translate(4,0)');
tickLabels.last()
  .attr('transform','translate(-4,0)');
```

---

Of course, you need to make sure that you only have one axis if you do it that way. Otherwise, specify the axis in your initial selection:

```
var tickLabels = svg.selectAll('.axis.x .tick text');
```

[**HERE**](http://jsbin.com/gozapu/1/edit?js,output) is an example.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks, I needed that and it works perfectly out of the box! +1

Comment: Just a short addendum: bear in mind that in d3.js v4 selectAll returns an different object, so you have to call nodes() method to get an object array. e.g. d3.selectAll(".axis.x .tick text").nodes()[0] for the first element

Comment: Just adding to what @stijena said. For d3 v4 and up, use  
`d3.selection.prototype.first = function() {  return d3.select(this.nodes()[0]);  };  ` and 
`d3.selection.prototype.last = function() {
  return d3.select(this.nodes()[this.size() - 1;]);
};`

Answer (score 11):

Here's the cleanest method I've found:

```
g.selectAll(".tick:first-of-type text").remove();
g.selectAll(".tick:last-of-type text").remove();
```

Answer (score 9):

As google brought me here, I also want to add a cleaner method to what Adam Grey wrote.
Sometimes you just want to do it without taking a reference of selectAll .

```
svg.selectAll('.gridlines').filter(function(d, i,list) {
    return i === list.length - 1;
}).attr('display', 'none');
```

the 3rd parameter of the filter function gives you the selected List of elements.

Answer (score 7):

They don't exist in d3 specifically, but you can use the `.firstChild` and `.lastChild` methods on a node.

You can first select all of the parents of the node, and then operate within the scope of a `.each()` method, like so:

```
d3.selectAll('.myParentElements').each(function(d,i){
  var firstChild = this.firstChild,
      lastChild = this.lastChild;

  //Do stuff with first and last child
});
```

Within the scope of `.each()`, `this` refers to the individual node, which is not wrapped by a d3 selection, so all of the standard methods on a node are available.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I'm accepting @jshanley's one as it's closer to what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Using `.filter()` with a function also works [*selection*.filter(filter)](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_filter) :

```
var gridlines;

gridlines = svg.selectAll('.gridlines');

gridlines.filter(function(d, i) {
  return i === gridlines.size() - 1;
}).attr('display', 'none');
```

Answer (score 3):

> It's for D3.js v4

```
d3.selection.prototype.first = function() {
    return d3.select(
        this.nodes()[0]
    );
};
d3.selection.prototype.last = function() {
    return d3.select(
        this.nodes()[this.size() - 1]
    );
};
```

> Example:

```
var lines = svg.selectAll('line');
   lines.first()
      .attr('transform','translate(4,0)');
   lines.last()
      .attr('transform','translate(-4,0)');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another, even though I used Fered's solution for a problem I met.

```
d3.select(d3.selectAll('*').nodes().reverse()[0])
```