# Selecting last path of svg with d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am fairly new in D3.js I want to build a real time collaborating blackboard. One admin client draw paths on svg and other clients receive them. I'm trying to pick last path element from clients side. I walked around last few hours finding several posts as  [How can I select :last-child in d3.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405359/how-can-i-select-last-child-in-d3-js) but cannot make it work. When i ask:

```
 console.log('svg ='+svg.selectAll("path")
```

having drawn two paths i get

```
svg ={"_groups":[{"0":{},"1":{}}],"_parents":[{"__on":[{"type":"click","name":"","capture":false},{"type":"mousedown","name":"drag","capture":false},{"type":"touchstart","name":"drag","capture":false},{"type":"touchmove","name":"drag","capture":false},{"type":"touchend","name":"drag","capture":false},{"type":"touchcancel","name":"drag","capture":false}]}]}
```

EDIT: my DOM structure

```
<svg id="myCanvas" width="960" height="500">
            <rect fill="#F2EDE4" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
        <path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" d="M223.64999389648438,304.25L223.98332722981772,304.5833333333333C224.31666056315103,304.9166666666667,224.98332722981772,305.5833333333333,226.31666056315103,306.75C227.64999389648438,307.9166666666667,229.64999389648438,309.5833333333333,231.14999389648438,310.4166666666667C232.64999389648438,311.25,233.64999389648438,311.25,234.98332722981772,310.4166666666667C236.31666056315103,309.5833333333333,237.98332722981772,307.9166666666667,238.81666056315103,307.0833333333333L239.64999389648438,306.25"></path><path></path></svg>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
const lastPath = d3.select('svg>path:last-child')
```

You should be able to use a string like `:last-child` in the d3 selection api.

Comment: I get  svg ={"_groups":[[{}]],"_parents":[{}]} no matter how many paths i draw. The only solution i think is to reverse path elements on svg given that svg.select("path") returns first element. But it is not an elegant solution

Comment: hmm ... what happens when you `console.log(d3.select('svg').node())`?

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure you have an svg element on your page?

Comment: I can see it clearly on Web Console inspector ( Firefox)

Comment: Very strange. I put your svg element into a [sample codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwVygx?editors=1010) and was able to select the last path and log it to the console ...

Comment: Thanks Peter . It works. I am not very sure what i did wrong yesterday but finally it works

Answer (score 2):

Peter's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44267891/5768908) **is** working.

You get a `{"_groups":[[{}]],"_parents":[{}]}`, as you said in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44265997/selecting-last-path-of-svg-with-d3-js#comment75544864_44267891), because that is a **D3 selection**, and that's the expected object.

If you want to get the DOM element, simply use the `node()` function:

```
const lastPath = d3.select('svg>path:last-child').node();
//getting the DOM element -------------------------^
```

Here is a demo using your SVG, it will log that empty path, which is the last one (since S.O. snippets freeze — at least in my machine, using Chrome — when trying to log D3 selections, [here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w5j3p7v5/) with the same code):

```js
const lastPath = d3.select('svg>path:last-child').node();
console.log(lastPath)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg id="myCanvas" width="960" height="500">
  <rect fill="#F2EDE4" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
  <path fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round" d="M223.64999389648438,304.25L223.98332722981772,304.5833333333333C224.31666056315103,304.9166666666667,224.98332722981772,305.5833333333333,226.31666056315103,306.75C227.64999389648438,307.9166666666667,229.64999389648438,309.5833333333333,231.14999389648438,310.4166666666667C232.64999389648438,311.25,233.64999389648438,311.25,234.98332722981772,310.4166666666667C236.31666056315103,309.5833333333333,237.98332722981772,307.9166666666667,238.81666056315103,307.0833333333333L239.64999389648438,306.25"></path>
  <path></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved this problem for me. According to [d3.selections](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection) docs, this is what you should do:

```
var lastPath = d3.selectAll('svg>path').filter(':last-child');
```