# How to select the second to last tag in a list?

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js, dom

I am new to frontend developing and working with d3.js. I have a problem with selecting a certain tag in a list of tags.

I created some graphs and I need to add an image to certain nodes. I tried to select the needed tag with `d3.select('g')`, but this selects the first tag. But I think the big problem is that the tags are called the same, and I don't know how to select the penultimate tag for example.

Here is my HTML code (short version):

```
<svg _ngcontent-c1="" width="1366" height="99">
   <gr _ngcontent-c1="" ng-reflect-zoomable-of="[object SVGSVGElement]">
      <g _ngcontent-c1="" _nghost-c2="" ng-reflect-link="[object Object]">
         <line _ngcontent-c2="" class="link" x1="1" y1="-2" x2="3" y2="-1"> </line>
      </g>
      <g _ngcontent-c1="" _nghost-c2="" ng-reflect-link="[object Object]">
         <line _ngcontent-c2="" class="link" x1="5" y1="2" x2="9" y2="4"> </line>
      </g>

   <g _ngcontent-c1="" ng-reflect-node="[object Object]" ng-reflect-draggable-node="[object Object]" ng-reflect-draggable-in-graph="[object Object]">
      <g transform="translate(3,4)">
         <text class="node-name" x="13" y="-3" font-size="20px">one</text>
      </g>
   </g>

   <g _ngcontent-c1="" ng-reflect-node="[object Object]" ng-reflect-draggable-node="[object Object]" ng-reflect-draggable-in-graph="[object Object]">
      <g transform="translate(5,6)">
             <text class="node-name" x="13" y="-3" font-size="20px">two </text>
          </g>
       </gr>
```

And my attempt to add an image:

```
var svg = d3.select('svg').select('gr').select('g')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', 64)
  .attr('height', 64)
  .style('border', '1px solid black');
var imgs = svg.selectAll('image').data([0]);
imgs.enter()
  .append('image')
  .attr('xlink:href', '/assets/ToNode.png')
  .attr('width', '64')
  .attr('height', '64');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging only by the title your question is a duplicate, `:last-child` being the obvious choice. There are several duplicate targets, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44265997/5768908). However, there is no answer showing how to select the penultimate element. Actually, if you search `penultimate` in the [d3.js](/questions/tagged/d3.js) tag, your question is the only result.

For selecting an element by a given index [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) is the most common option, or, since you are counting from the end, [`:nth-last-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child). But I'd like to give you an answer showing how to use the second and third parameters (of most D3 methods) combined.

In several D3 methods (like `filter`, which I'll use in this answer), the second parameter is the index of the element relative to the selection, while the third parameter is the current group, or nodes, which make up that selection. Those parameters are normally named `i` and `n`, but you can name them anyway you want. The important information here is that `n.length` gives us the number of elements.

So, if we select all `<g>` elements, we can get the penultimate one using:

```
yourSelection.filter(function(_, i, n) {
    return i === n.length - 2
  })
```

Here, I'm using `n.length - 2` because the indices are zero-based, therefore `n.length - 1` is the last element. Also, `_` is just a convention that says that we are not using the first parameter anywhere in the function.

Here is a demo, if you inspect the SVG you'll see that a dummy element `<foo>` was added to the penultimate group:

```js
d3.selectAll("g").filter(function(_, i, n) {
    return i === n.length - 2
  })
  .append("foo")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <g></g>
  <g></g>
  <g></g>
  <g></g>
  <g></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: The most obvious choice would probably be `g:nth-last-child(2)`. Good answer though. I really enjoy answers pointing out different, non-obvious approaches. Alas, one is very likely to take a beating for posting such answers.

Comment: For the sake of clean, maintainable code one should stick to a single, often used approach. `el:nth-last-child(n)` is implemented for *exactly* this use case (selecting the nth-to-last element). Why use something different?

Comment: @ThomasPötzsch Because this is D3. Sometimes the user needs to select the element in a `selection.each`, or in the callback of an `attr` or `style` methods, or in the event listener defined by `selection.on`... in all those cases CSS selectors cannot be used.

Comment: oh, ok. I was just asking out of pure curiosity, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @ThomasPötzsch As OP stated *"I have a problem with selecting a certain tag in a list of tags.*" and *"I don't know how to select the penultimate tag for example"*, Gerardo's approach is the most general applicable solution (at least involving D3). Re-reading the post I have a feeling that selecting the second to last element was meant to be more of an example rather than a specific use case; the question seems to be just short of an XY-problem. As long as we don't know OP's objective this answer is just as valid as any other because there are no metrics by which to judge its applicability.