# D3 Js how to select the last child in an bar chart

Tags: d3.js

According to [select last child topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405359/how-can-i-select-last-child-in-d3-js) I've tried to select the last chart element like this:

```
    d3.selection.prototype.first = function() {
       return d3.select(this[0][0]);
};
    d3.selection.prototype.last = function() {
      var last = this.size() - 1;
      return d3.select(this[0][last]);
};
this.svg.selectALl('bar: rect').last().style("fill","red");
```

But the color will not be changed.

Comment: Can you create a codepen for your problem.

Comment: The solution you copied over is for D3 **v3**. You are probably using **>=v4** which requires a slightly different approach. Fortunately, the question you linked to has an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47706733/4235784) which has got you covered.